# Writing CSV gives, Error : could not convert string to float

Tags: python, csv, sage

I have a problem adding a CSV file into Python, I write this program:

```py
import csv

file=r'C:Users\kloner\Desktop\Stage\partactions.csv'
reader=csv.reader(open(file, encoding = "ISO-8859-1"))

liste=[]

for row in reader:
    liste.append(row)

liste.pop(0)
M=matrix(RDF,liste)
print(M)
```

But it gives me the following error:

> Error : could not convert string to float

[image]

Comment: Which line you are getting an error? can you mentioned where exactly the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

I think matrix is np.matrix and some code are strange.

Maybe it should like this.

```py
import csv
from numpy import matrix

file=r'C:Users\kloner\Desktop\Stage\partactions.csv'
reader=csv.reader(open(file, encoding = "ISO-8859-1"))

liste=[]
for row in reader:
    liste.append(row)
liste.pop(0)
M=matrix(liste)
print(M)
```

Comment: @Kloner if this answer fixed your problem, you can click the checkmark next to the answer to mark it as accepted and help others find it